# Stop Sprite Rotating as it moves on a circle path?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently running the following code on a sprite node.

```
// the circle path's diameter
    let circleDiameter = CGFloat(150)

    // center our path based on our sprites initial position
    let pathCenterPoint = CGPoint(
        x: player.position.x - circleDiameter/2,
        y: player.position.y - circleDiameter/2
    )

    // create the path our sprite will travel along
    let circlePath = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: pathCenterPoint, size: CGSize(width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter)), transform: nil)

    // create a followPath action for our sprite
    let followCirclePath = SKAction.follow(circlePath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 4)

    // make our sprite run this action forever
    player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(followCirclePath))
    self.addChild(player)
```

Currently the code works fine, however the player rotates as it moves in a circle path. Is there anyway I can stop the player sprite from rotating as well, as it moves in a circle?

Cheers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change this line:

```
let followCirclePath = SKAction.follow(circlePath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 4)
```

To this:

```
let followCirclePath = SKAction.follow(circlePath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 4)
```

Just set orientToPath to false.

For reference, this is documented by Apple in the following document:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417798-follow

Comment: *Face Palm* Thanks! Works well now :D Also cheers for the the reference as well! Ill have a look!